# React best practicies: pass state down to child or have child check state directly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using react/redux.  I have a program which has two components, call them foo and bar.  Foo needs to set a state that bar will use to decide how to render.  I have foo using a dispatcher to dispatch an action and the reducer is using the action to set the global state, all good so far.

My question is who should load it.  Is it better to have my index (which renders foo and bar) to check state and then pass the state value down to bar as a prop, or to have bar cut out the middle man and check state directly.

To be more exact I'm wondering rather the developers of react/redux have supported a specific approach, or if this is one of those design decisions where either approach is viable so long as a developer stays consistent?

Comment: have state as low as possible in the hierarchy so that elements don't rerender unnecessarily (aka if only bar needs it, have it in bar)

Comment: It's better to add some example code otherwise only long text looks boring and people will not show interest in your question.

Comment: In Short; Manipulate the parent component state value to all child component props is a best approach. only parent i mean container should have react-reduct connect pipes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main recommendations when using redux and react is to keep in mind the **Presentational and Container components** patterns, in this pattern our presentational components are not aware of the existence of redux and receives data from props, while the container components are the ones who subscribe to react state and pass it down to the presentational components:

Here you got a presentational component, as you can see it has no relation to react.

```
const TodoList = ({ todos, onTodoClick }) => (
  <ul>
    {todos.map((todo, index) => (
      <Todo key={index} {...todo} onClick={() => onTodoClick(index)} />
    ))}
  </ul>
)
```

In order to have a container component, we would `connect` that component and subscribe it to react's state, like:

```
const VisibleTodoList = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoList)
```

​
You can get more information [here](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#presentational-and-container-components)